# Php script installation: what is best way to install sqlite.db file

Tags: php, database, sqlite, installation

I am doing installation file for php script. And i'm looking way for installation sqlite3 db for this script with tables and some base data.

**What is the best way for it?**

**How it looks for me:**

1) copy file db.sqlite3 - binary file

2) creating empty file and using query putting all data. (like for mysql) *if it's possible

Thanks!

Comment: Both will be same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best wat is:

1. copy .sqlite3 file
2. generate path, file names by random (in
       your install file)